# React Native RefreshControl pulling up

Tags: react-native

RefreshComponent works by showing a loader when you pull down. [The documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol.html) states:

> When the ScrollView is at scrollY: 0, swiping down triggers an onRefresh event.

Is there a way to trigger the onRefresh event by pulling up? When I reach the end of a ListView I want to be able to trigger the onRefresh event by pulling up.

Currently, this is what I have:

```js
<ListView
  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
  renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
  style={styles.listView}
  refreshControl={
    <RefreshControl
      refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
      onRefresh={this.fetchData.bind(this)}
    />
  }
/>
```

This works for pulling down, but that's not what I need.

Comment: You can have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087775/how-to-implement-pull-up-to-load-more-in-react-native-using-listview-for-android#40088041)