# How to implement pull up to load more in React Native using ListView for Android?

Tags: react-native

It's like the opposite of pull down to refresh. ListView on Android does not support bounces.

Answer (score 13):

To achieve infinite scroll on `ListView` you can use `onEndReached` and `renderFooter` from `ListView` component. It could looks like this (you just `renderFooter` when `onEndReached` is triggered)

```
onEndReached() {
    if (!this.state.waiting) {
        this.setState({waiting: true});
        this.fetchData() // fetching new data, ended with this.setState({waiting: false});
    }
}

renderFooter() {
    if (this.state.waiting) {
        return <ActivityIndicator />;
    } else {
        return <Text>~</Text>;
    }
}

render() {
  return (
    <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={this.renderRow}
      renderFooter={this.renderFooter}
      onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
    />);
}
```

Another way is to use some of libraries:

- https://github.com/exponentjs/react-native-infinite-scroll-view
- https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-listview

I tried with remobile, but it was deprecated (and too complicated, you have to implement about 4-5 method to satisfy this component). I used FaridSafi, it's ok but refresh is on click, not on pull.